# import CSV file and replacing already defined text eg mail merge

Tags: macos, csv, text-editor, nstextfield, mailmerge

I have created an Xcode project for a Mac OSX system, What i want to be able to do is import a csv file and it will replace certain words in the open document with the data in the CSV file.

e.g. when the user opens the application, the app already has the letter written out for them, they then import a CSV file (which the format of the CSV file never changes just the data) and it will replace certain words in the letter with the data from the CSV file (like a mail merge in word or pages)

I am using an NSText Field for the letter so that the user can change the letter if required.

The CSV file has the following headings: State, Name, Expires
I only need the Name and Expires Field to fill into the pre drafted text field.

Thank you

Comment: Editing to remove all mentions of Xcode, since Xcode is simply your development environment and has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i am literally just starting to use the Objective C language but have a basic under standing of C and other formes so i dont know exactly were to start

Comment: Perhaps something like Docmosis will help if you are actually talking about populating Documents?  No help if you actually want to populate on-screen forms as your final result.